# Summing A Defined Previous Loop on Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, sum

I am attempting to try and sum an array I have created in Ruby. I'm using an integer (10) as an example, but the code must be able to allow any type of integer to be plugged into it. I must plug in a number, & have Ruby find any #'s from 0 to that plugged in number that are divisible by 3 & 5. Numbers should never repeat in the array. Then I need to have those numbers summed. I have created the loop to find those numbers, but my problem is I cannot figure out how to then sum those numbers in the array after. I have googled so many different options, and none have worked. I am very new at this, but I am trying desperately to figure things out. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Here is my code so far, & I know the summing loop doesn't work, but I am showing how I tried:

Attempt #1:

```
def sum_multiples(num)
  mult = []
  i = 1
  while i < num
    if i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0
      mult << i
    end
    i += 1
  end
  return mult
end

def summing(array)
  array = mult
  sum = 0
  array.each do |x|
  end
  sum += x
end

puts sum_multiples(10)
```

Attempt #2:

```
def sum_multiples(num)
  mult = []
  i = 1
  while i < num
    if i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0
      mult << i
    end
    i += 1
  end
  return mult
end

def summing(array)
  array = mult
  array.each { |a| sum += a }
  return array
end

puts sum_multiples(10)
```

Comment: In your attempt#1, `sum += x` occurs **outside** of the loop. I would expect that you get here an error message about an undefined variable _x_.

Comment: Why don't you simply write `array.sum`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well what you are attempting to do, you can do it easy with the next function:

```
# sum all numbers from 0 to `num` that are divisible by 3 & 5
# then sum and return the result
# @param num [Integer] An unsigned integer greater than 0.
# @return [Integer]

def sum_multiples(num)
  ((0..num).select { |e| (e % 3).zero? && (e % 5).zero? }).sum
end

# we know that all numbers divisible by 3 and 5 are multiples of 15
# so this must print 45

p sum_multiples(30)
```

Explaining a bit, first we create a range from 0 to the given number, then we filter the numbers that we need, then we sum the resulting array.

Comment: Instead of `select { ... }.sum` you can also directly call `sum { ... }`

Comment: Yes @Stefan! You are right! It will be looking like: `(0..num).sum { |e| (e % 3).zero? && (e % 5).zero? }`

Answer (score 0):

In your first attempt you have defined a `summing` method, but you are not using it - which is a good thing because it does not work at all. The good news is that a arrays do have a `sum` method, so if you change the line `return mult` to `return mult.sum` you'll see some progress.

Comment: Please note also that the last expression in a method is its return value, and `return` is only _needed_ to break control flow early.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sum_multiples` method seems to be the one returning numbers that are multiples of 3 and / or 5. It doesn't however *sum* these numbers, so I would remove that prefix:

```
def multiples(num)
  # ...
end
```

You also said *"from 0 to that plugged in number"* so you should start from `0`:

```
def multiples(num)
  mult = []
  i = 0             # <----- 0, not 1
  while i < num
    if i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0
      mult << i
    end
    i += 1
  end
  return mult
end
```

Let's give it a try:

```
multiples(10)
#=> [0, 3, 5, 6, 9]
```

Looks good. One minor suggestion: the method call `multiples(10)` *looks* as if it would return multiples of 10 (which it does not). It never mentions `3` or `5` and I would be quite surprised to get that result if I didn't know its implementation. Maybe a more descriptive name for the method and a [keyword argument](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments) with an appropriate name could help, e.g. `multiples_of_3_and_5(upto: 10)`. For now however, it's good enough.

Now for part 2:

> Then I need to have those numbers summed.

For your `summing` method, you define an argument `array`:

```
def summing(array)
  #
end
```

When you call the method, you have to *pass* that argument, e.g.:

```
summing([1, 2, 3])
#       ^^^^^^^^^
#   passed-in argument
```

This will automatically set the `array` variable to the passed value (the array `[1, 2, 3]`). You don't have to set it yourself:

```
def summing(array)
  array = mult  # <-- not needed, and in fact "mult" is never defined
  # ...
end
```

In your loop you increment `sum` via `+=`. In order to get this working, `sum` needs an initial value:

```
def summing(array)
  sum = 0
  array.each { |a| sum += a }
  # ...
end
```

The last issue is `summing`'s return value. The method is supposed to calculate the sum of the elements in `array`. I would expect it to also *return* the calculated sum:

```
def summing(array)
  sum = 0
  array.each { |a| sum += a }
  return sum  # <-- not array
end
```

Let's try it:

```
summing([1, 2, 3])
#=> 6

summing([10, 20])
#=> 30
```

To plug both methods together, I'd use variables to store the return values:

```
numbers = multiples(10)
#=> [0, 3, 5, 6, 9]

sum = summing(numbers)
#=> 23
```

If you don't need the numbers, you could also write:

```
sum = summing(multiples(10))
#=> 23
```

i.e. just replace `numbers` by the expression you previously assigned to it.

---

Note that your code isn't very idiomatic. You rarely use `while` loops in Ruby or explicit counters or explicit `return` statements.

Here's a more idiomatic implementation using a [`Range`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Range.html) and [`Enumerable#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#select-method) to fetch the numbers, and [`Array#sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#sum-method) for summing:

```
def multiples(num)
  (0..num).select { |i| i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0 }
end

def summing(array)
  array.sum
end
```

The `summing` method is merely a wrapper now, you can just as well call the built-in `sum` directly:

```
numbers = multiples(10)
sum     = numbers.sum
```

or

```
sum = multiples(10).sum
#=> 23
```